# IIS 7 Completely Disable Caching

Tags: php, iis-7, caching

No matter what I do iis still caching my php files. I unchecked all caching options and rechecked configuration file and it seems okay.

How should I completely turn off all kinds of caching? By the way my php file is quite simple its just echo "somestring"

Comment: how do you know it's iis that's caching the file and not your browser caching the output?

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit late but it might be useful for somebody else.

Are you using PHP Wincache? If you are, just add `wincache.fcenabled=0` to your php.ini file.

http://php.net/manual/en/wincache.configuration.php